# SharePoint converting ID value into display Name after submitting Infopath form

Tags: sharepoint, infopath2010

I am using Infopath to design a form and basically I used a cascade filtering system to filter depending on my criteria. So the value of category "B" is dependent on category "A". However I am running into a problem. Once I submit the form , the display name shows in the form but once submitted is shows the value, for example "42" on the Sharepoint List site. How could I fix this problem?

Answer (score 0):

set the drop-down properties Value to "Product name" instead of "ID".

SET:

*Value:* Product Name 
*Display Name:* Product Name

NOT:

*Value:* ID 
*Display Name:* Product Name